# Undefined beans with Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, nullpointerexception

I'm having trouble understanding Spring MVC. 
I have the following web.xml :

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>RESTServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        <async-supported>true</async-supported>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>RESTServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

In the root-context.xml file, I declare various beans, some with xml and the others with annotations :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- Root Context: defines shared resources visible to all other web components -->

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.dynamease.**" />
    <context:annotation-config />

    <!-- Configures External Property Resolution -->
    <import resource="properties.xml" />

    <!-- Configures Shared Data Access Resources -->
    <import resource="data.xml" />

    <bean id="contextSource" class="org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource">
        <property name="url" value="ldap://192.168.1.10:10389" />
        <property name="base" value="dc=dynamease,dc=net" />
        <property name="userDn" value="uid=admin,ou=system" />
        <property name="password" value="secret" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="ldapTemplate" class="org.springframework.ldap.core.LdapTemplate">
        <constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

In the servlet-context.xml, I define beans related to the web logic :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
        infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <interceptors>
        <beans:bean
            class="com.dynamease.entity.springsocialentities.UserInterceptor">
            <beans:constructor-arg ref="usersConnectionRepository" />
        </beans:bean>
    </interceptors>

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
        up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
        in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- Imports user-defined @Controller beans that process client requests -->
    <bean class="com.dynamease.web.rest.HomeController">
        <constructor-arg ref="facebook" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Allows users to sign-in with their provider accounts.  -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.social.connect.web.ProviderSignInController">
        <constructor-arg ref="connectionFactoryLocator" />
        <constructor-arg ref="usersConnectionRepository" />     
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean class="com.dynamease.entity.springsocialentities.SimpleSignInAdapter" />
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <mvc:view-controller path="/signin" />

    <mvc:view-controller path="/signout" />
</beans:beans>
```

The trouble is that beans defined in root-context.xml aren't initialized (I get Null pointer Exception trying to access them). 
For instance, in the HomeController bean :

```
@Autowired
    private DynDirectoryServiceImpl dynDirectoryService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(Model model) {
        System.out.println("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<");
        System.out.println(this.getClass().toString());
        System.out.println(dynDirectoryService.toString()); 
}
```

The last line fails.

Here is the DynDirectoryServiceImpl code :

```
    @Component
    public class DynDirectoryServiceImpl implements DynDirectoryServiceInterface {

        @Autowired
        private LdapTemplate ldapTemplate;

        @Autowired
        private OdmManager odmManager;

        @Override
        public boolean verify(DynContact dynContact) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }
}
```

Comment: I don't see `DynDirectoryServiceImpl` being created in your `root-context.xml` file.  Is it picked up via package scanning?

Comment: Yes, in the root-context.xml file.

Comment: @fxm show the annotions have you got the name correct ?

Comment: The code itself is correct, it runs perfectly without the servlet system.

Comment: @fxm..  I assume problem lies here. Try Changing this to  `base-package="com.dynamease.**` to `base-package="com.dynamease` in your xml file.

Comment: Changed it but I still get the error.

Comment: @fxm.. Can you post exact error stack? So, it's easy to narrow down the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try and change the type of the autowired property:

```
@Autowired
private DynDirectoryServiceInterface
```

You are also missing the

```
<context:annotation-config />
```

element in the MVC config.

Comment: It didn't seem to change something.

Answer (score 1):

First, a few thoughts on your code: 
You're implementing an interface (which is good), but not using it (which is bad). When you are autowiring the DynDirectoryServiceImpl, you are bypassing the interface. The purpose of an Interface is to not allow other entities to look directly at how you are implementing your code.

To autowire using the Interface, I would name the interface the generic name (i.e.: "DynDirectoryService") then in the Impl class have "@Component("DynDirectoryService")". When using the class you do "@Autowire private DynDirectoryService variableName;"

One important thing to note when doing this: you must have the method name synced between the implementation and the interface. If you want to do this without making major changes to your current code, just make it "@Component("DynDirectoryServiceInterface")" then when using it do "@Autowired DynDirectoryServiceInterface variableName;"

Regarding your issue with the line

```
System.out.println(dynDirectoryService.toString());
```

Note that in your dynDirectoryServiceImpl class you don't have a .toString() method. You may need to write one. This is supposed to be one of the automatically included methods, but I have seen it not be included before, or it will just spit out giberish that is the instance of the that class being used. (i.e.: DynDirectoryServiceImpl@635446138792). Try adding this to the implementation and the interface and see if it helps anything:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Hello, this is toString()";
}
```

Additionally, like @SrinivasR said, your component scan should not be

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.dynamease.**" />
```

unless you actually have a package called "**" in "com.dynamease" otherwise it should be

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.dynamease" />
```

The component-scan will auto-magically look inside all sub packages in "com.dynamease".